# Postgres client unable to detect UTF-8 database

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, character-set, encoding

**Context**

I am deploying a Vagrant box for my development team, and have encountered a problem restoring UTF-8 collated dumps. I don't believe it is related to the now-infamous *"UTF8" has no equivalent in "LATIN1"* problem, as my issue seems to lie in the client. Additionally, I have successfully restored exactly the same dump files on other Precise boxes (though precise64) with the same client and server packages (9.1). However, *I am uncertain* if other supporting libraries may not be present in my Vagrant box.

I can not alter the way in which the dump files are created, but I don't believe the problem lies there, anyway.

**Problem**

I successfully programatically create and restore a UTF-8 (specifically, `en_CA.UTF-8`) dump by [creating a table with](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/multibyte.html):

```
createdb --lc-collate=en_CA.UTF-8 --lc-ctype=en_CA.UTF-8 -E UTF8 -T template0 ${SCHEMA}
```

(If relevant, I'll add that my other successful restores (on the precise64 system) did not require any additional locale parameters to `createdb`.)

Then restore,

```
pg_restore -d ${SCHEMA} --single-transaction /tmp/${SCHEMA}_-_latest.backup
```

I have attempted with both [postgresql.conf's](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-CLIENT-ENCODING) `client_encoding` commented out *and* manually set to `client_encoding = 'UTF8'`; both behave the same.

My /etc/default/locale contains

```
LC_ALL=en_CA.UTF-8
LANG=en_CA.UTF-8
```

**And yet**, at the `psql` prompt:

```
schema=# SELECT * FROM table;
ERROR:  character 0xe28099 of encoding "UTF8" has no equivalent in "LATIN1"

schema=# show server_encoding; show client_encoding;
 server_encoding 
-----------------
 UTF8
(1 row)

 client_encoding 
-----------------
 LATIN1
(1 row)
```

The schema is UTF-8, right (so the commented-out `client_encoding` should use this value)?

```
schema=# SELECT pg_encoding_to_char(encoding) FROM pg_database WHERE datname = ...
pg_encoding_to_char 
---------------------
 UTF8
(1 row)
```

Setting it manually at the command prompt works:

```
schema=# set client_encoding to UTF8
SET
schema=# show client_encoding;
 client_encoding 
-----------------
 UTF8
(1 row)

schema=# SELECT * FROM table;
<EXPECTED DATA>
```

What have I done wrong?

EDIT for Craig:

```
vagrant@precise32:~$ locale
LANG=en_CA.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`psql` detects the `client_encoding` from the `LC_CTYPE` variable in the environment; this falls back to `LC_ALL` and then `LANG` if unset.

In the terminal you're launching `psql` from, run `locale`. e.g.

```
$ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Paste the result as an edit to your question. I strongly suspect your terminal locale will be `en_CA`, not `en_CA.UTF-8`.

Comment: Great thinking, Craig. Unfortunately…it is indeed `en_CA.UTF-8` (full `locale` edit added).

Comment: Thought I am ashamed to admit it, I wonder if I neglected to re-source the new locale in my virtual machine, as it works now.

Answer (score 0):

Edited for formatting, locale env and clarifying NOT TO USE SQL_ASCII as pointed out by @Craig Ringer (upvote 1, don't have enough reputation :) )

```
This worked for me (excuse the actual encoding used :) )

1. comment it in postgresql.conf file
#client_encoding = 'UTF-8' # actually, defaults to database 
                           # encoding
2. export LANG=''
**************** this is what was tested ****************

postgres@host> locale 
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
....
LC_ALL=
postgres@host> psql
psql (9.2.4)
Type "help" for help.
postgres=# \c db
You are now connected to database "db" as user "postgres".
db=# show server_encoding; show client_encoding;
server_encoding
-----------------
SQL_ASCII
(1 row)
client_encoding
-----------------
UTF8
(1 row)

db=# \q
postgres@host> export LANG=''

postgres@host> psql 
psql (9.2.4)
Type "help" for help.
postgres=# \c db
You are now connected to database "db" as user "postgres".
db=# show server_encoding; show client_encoding;
server_encoding
-----------------
SQL_ASCII
(1 row)
client_encoding
-----------------
SQL_ASCII
(1 row)

> locale 
LANG=
LC_CTYPE="POSIX"
....
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I [don't think](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/multibyte.html) that will work for me: *"In most cases, if you are working with any non-ASCII data, it is unwise to use the SQL_ASCII setting, because PostgreSQL will be unable to help you by converting or validating non-ASCII characters."*

Comment: Additionally, I *want* my `LANG` environment variable to be `en_CA.UTF-8`. Clever, though.

Comment: `SQL_ASCII` is a bad idea. It wouldn't be supported if the SQL spec didn't require it. Please don't advise its use without explaining the risks and problems carefully. (Also, please read the markdown formatting guide for stack overlfow).

Comment: yes SQL_ASCII is a bad idea, hence my comment earlier about "excuse the encoding" :)
this is an old project i've inherited - we are moving to uft8. I'll post the environment setting as a separate comment. Apologies for the formatting, will spend time on that too.